# This does not seem to be a “Debug” build

Tags: android, c++, gcc, qt5, qt-creator

I’m trying to use a debugger with an android device and get the window with such a warning message:

```
    This does not seem to be a "Debug" build.
    Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail.

    Section .debug_info: Not found.
    Section .debug_abbrev: Not found.
    Section .debug_line: Not found.
    Section .debug_str: Not found.
    Section .debug_loc: Not found.
    Section .debug_range: Not found.
    Section .gdb_index: Not found.
    Section .note.gnu.build-id: Not found.
    Section .gnu.hash: Not found.
    Section .gnu_debuglink: Not found.
```

I’m using the Qt Creator 2.8.1 based on Qt 5.1.1 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit).
The Qt libraries, the application and all the depends was built with the GCC 4.8.

The most strange thing in this situation that I can use a debugger for the main Application, but all libraries are not able for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the library type from dynamic to static.

P.S. Maybe someone knows why the dynamic libraries are not able for debugging under android?

Comment: How did you change the library type to static?